# convert a sentence to ascii code in c++

Tags: c++

i want to convert a sentence like 'good boy' to ascii code . i know the code that is a loop and print the ascii code of each character of sentence but i don't want this. i want that the ascii code of sentence (all characters alltogether) in long for example 1259788712..

Comment: What did you try so far? What is your specific problem? How is it `C` if the title includes `C++`?

Comment: Do you expect to recover the sentence from the ascii code of the sentence?

Comment: Very unclear how you want to get that result. Can you please show an example of what `long` (presumably) value should correspond to `"AB"` and why (bonus for sample for `"ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQ"`)

Comment: @sameerkn yes. exactly

Comment: You can typecast strings into integers, as long as the string is not longer than the integer type you want to use. So if you are on a 32 bit system, you could turn a 4 byte string into a number..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov for example for sentence "AB" i want output 6566

Comment: `long` is a data type which has limited representable values. So not all sentences can be covered by a `long` variable. If you have predefined finite set of sentences then things can be though of.

Comment: @sameerkn assume just two character

Comment: 1) Get the int value of each char `(int)c`, 2) parse each int into corresponding string value `to_string(...)`, 3) append each string value to a string empty at first `str += string_value`, then 4) parse the string into a long `std::stol(str)`

Comment: you mean your sentences will have words each of just 2 characters. Then how many words can be present in a sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string to handle it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>  // use stringstream
using namespace std;
// turn int into string
string IntTOstring(int);

int main(void)
{
    string sIn,sOut;

    // input 
    sIn = "good boy";

    sOut="";
    for (int i=0 ; i<sIn.length() ; i++ ) {
        // get one char from sIn each time
        int temp=sIn.c_str()[i];

        // turn int into string & save in sOut
        sOut += IntTOstring(temp);
    }

    cout << sOut << endl;

    return 0;
}
// use stringstream to convert int to string
string IntTOstring(int i){
    stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. my problem have been solved becuase of your help. thanks